# Multiline TextView with width "wrap_content"

Tags: android, textview

I am wondering how to have a `TextView` display its content on several lines [without hardcoding the width in the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674578/multiline-textview-in-android).

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Long multiline text"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any thought welcome.

**EDIT**: my problem is that when the text exceeds the width set (because it reaches the end of the screen) a portion of the text is just not displayed. I would expect the text to be split on two lines

Comment: I'm confused by what you want.  When the TextView reaches the width of its parent, then a new lines starts. Other than that where _do_ you want the lines breaks? You can manually break the line with: `android:text="long \nmultiline \ntext"`. You can also use the `maxWidth` attribute to wrap the TextView around the content until a desired width.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question with more details

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior of a `TextView`? What happens if you remove `maxLines` and `singleLine`?

Comment: If I set the layout_width to a fixed value, it works. But I can't do that as the TextView has to fill the available space

Comment: Is this in a HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: It's in a LinearLayout. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Do you really need the second `TextView` with the fixed width?

Comment: If I copy paste your xml file, the text gets wrapped as expected (only increasing the length of the text), it only is moved a bit off the screen. I will post a possible solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Though I cannot reproduce the not wrapping problem, you can fix the positioning problem by using a `weight` on the first `TextView`. Using the following XML gives the expected output in the graphical layout view in Eclipse:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Long multiline text"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What a ridiculous bug!

Comment: android:singleLine is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Also add

```
android:minLines="2"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

in your TextView XML. This worked for me.

Comment: This is incorrect - android:inputType should only be used for EditText - use singleLine = false for textViews

Comment: @RMcGuigan, TextView also has an XML attribute called android:inputType. Please see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.

Comment: It does yes, but it should not be used for setting textview to multi-line - as per lint warning. See my original comment for the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

I think I had very similar problem. I had a `TextView` with a text, where I was not sure how much lines will it take. It was encapsulated by a `LinearLayout` having `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to ensure my text will fill out all the space horizontally. However, the problem was that my text did not fit into 1 line and when it did break into a new line, the next view component below it did not move downwards to give enough space for the second line to be viewable fully.

I could achieve the solution by changing the `LinearLayout` that was containing my `TextView` into a **`RelativeLayout`**. By this way, the element below the text (actually below the Layout itself) was moved automatically to give enough space for the multi-line text.