# How can I set a multiline TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` in `Android` that shows the information that it's retrieved from a database so I don't know how much lines will be used for show the information.

This is my `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

And what I tried it's to put the property `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` but it gives to me an advice:

> Attribute `android:inputType` should not be used with `<TextView>`: Change element type to `<EditText>`?

I searched on Internet but in all answers they know the maximum lines that they need, so they use the property `android:maxLines="the maximum of lines they want"` or `android:lines="the total of lines that the TextView has"` but I don't want that because I don't know how much lines I will have in my `TextView`.

How can I make a `TextView` with an **undefined** number of lines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TextView supports unlimited lines by default. Are you talking about how many lines are visible?

Comment: this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674578/multiline-textview-in-android

Comment: @adelphus I suppose it is with putting the number of Lines, right? But you makes me open my eyes and know I got what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You have hard coded the margin in your textView, that could be the reason that it is not expanding according to the text entered, check if there  is any view below your textview and you've hardcoded the margin of that view from this textView.

Comment: @VaishaliSharma Now I have what I wanted but, in your opinion, how should I put a margin? Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote is? Is it something wrong on the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use following xml. Hopefully it will work.

```
<EditText 
...
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```